# FOREIGN KEY MULTI FIELD HELP!

Tags: foreign-keys

I have 2 table

```
TABLE CLASS
(
    school varchar(50),
    year   varchar(50),
    grade  varchar(50),
    className varchar(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (school,year,grade,className)
)
TABLE STUDENT
(
    student_id varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    detail varchar(50)
)
```

Now, I want to subclass for students. How to create a reference?

Comment: What programming language is this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do what everyone else does...

```
CREATE TABLE CLASS (
    id int not null auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, -- CREATE A KEY COLUMN
    school varchar(50),
    year   varchar(50),
    grade  varchar(50),
    className varchar(50),
    unique (school,year,grade,className)
);

CREATE TABLE STUDENT (
    student_id varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    class_id int references class,  -- REFERENCE THE KEY
    detail varchar(50)
);
```

Comment: duplicate data when adding the id. (school,year,grade,className). way better?